# Trivial / Non trivial all pass system

Tags: matlab, signal

у меня такая задача, помогите пожалуйста ее решить.
https://imgur.com/a/3nVTe8t

Explain if a cascade of two of the above systems (AB, AC, or BC) leads to a
non-trivial all-pass system. If yes, what is the order of that all-pass system ?
Note: a trivial all-pass system has a transfer function of the form *H(z) = Gz^-d*, where *G* is a constant
gain and  is a constant delay *d*